# Convert assembly language macros to plain assembly language

Tags: assembly, macros, masm

In MASM, is it possible to convert macro instructions to the corresponding assembly language instructions? I want to convert MASM's macro instructions to plain assembly language instructions, so that I can see how the macros actually work.

For example, I'd like to convert these macro instructions to the corresponding assembly language instructions (without macros):

```
.if(x > 5)
    mov eax, x
.else
    mov ebx, x
.endif
```

Comment: Of course the easiest way to do that is to actually have MASM assemble the file and have it generate an output list. I forget how to do that - I haven't used MASM in years - but I know there used to be a command-line switch to generate an output listing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going to suggest "generate a listing" like [500-InternalServerError](https://stackoverflow.com/users/448932/500-internal-server-error) proposed, but after verifying it, that won't work - the listing contains only your instructions, not MASM-generated ones. What does work is the following:

1) Assemble with debug info:

```
ml /c /Zi file.asm
```

2) disassemble with `dumpbin` (or another disassembler):

```
dumpbin /disasm file.obj
```

For the example above, it produces:

```
$$000000:
  00000000: 83 3D 00 00 00 00  cmp         dword ptr [x],5
            05
  00000007: 76 04              jbe         @C0001
  00000009: 8B C2              mov         eax,edx
  0000000B: EB 02              jmp         @C0003
@C0001:
  0000000D: 8B DA              mov         ebx,edx
```